# Is my HTML File Loading my CSS and JS files correctly?

Tags: html, shiny

Below is my HTML document to implement a JavaScript library into my Shiny App.  In my HTML document, I am referencing the .css files and the .js files that are in my www directory.  However, whenever I load my App, it shows only the image border, with a blue question mark in the middle.  In my UI.R file, I have the following code that calls for the .HTML file.  Can anyone see where either my HTML or my R code is incorrect?

```
tabPanel("Test Panel 1",
           mainPanel(
             includeHTML("www/basic.html")
           )
           )
```

I modified my HTML code, and it works when I click the HTML link in my File Explorer, but in Shiny, it doesn't load at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <title>taggd basic demo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="taggd.css" />

    <style>
        img {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.taggd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<img src="WhirlpoolDishwasher.jpg" class="taggd" alt="" />

<script>
    var options = {
        align: {
            y: 'top'
        },

        offset: {
            top: 15
        },

        handlers: {
            click: 'toggle'
        }
    };

    var data = [
        { x: 0.62, y: 0.7, text: 'Rope'             },

    ];

    var taggd = $('.taggd').taggd( options, data );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We'd have to know more about how Shiny calls up this HTML template to fully answer this question. Try running `pwd` at the root of your shiny app to figure out the real paths of the files in the question.

Comment: I ran `getwd()` which is the working directory in R.  It returned: 'C:/Users/brennn1/Documents/myApp'.  My `www` folder is stored in `myApp`.

Comment: try absolute paths to those files

Comment: Absolute paths did indeed work!

Comment: Ok, that's a good start. Now walk the paths back to step by step until you can find the depth at which the app is reading your files correctly.